# add input and button inside select react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi guys anyone know how to add input and button inside select

This is my code

```
<select
        className="w3-select w3-border"
        name="country"
        onChange={onChange}
      >
        <option value="DEFAULT" selected disabled hidden>
          Select Country :
        </option>
        {allcountry.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <option key={index} value={item.countryname}>
              {item.countryname}
            </option>
          );
        })}
      </select>
```

[image: This is the result]

I want add input and button inside the Select Country , so when I input the `allcountry` state will update, Thank you :D

Comment: Sorry I couldn't understand why you need input and button inside select. Isn't onChange enough for updating state on country update? 
Also, look into react-select.

Comment: I don't think it's possible with the standard `select` and `option` html elements. Permitted content for `select` is zero or more `<option>` or `<optgroup>` elements, and permitted contend for `option` is text, possibly with escaped characters (like `&eacute;`). Are you trying to achieve something like [react-select](https://react-select.com/home)?